# Python - Am I able to remove some of the punctuation from a random.sample output?

Tags: python, discord.py

So I decided to take a crack at my first Python/Discord bot to make it easier to play a game me and my friends made up.

```py
my_list = ["Doom", "Rabid", "Streaker", "Dukes Up",
 "Duelist", "Thorough", "Deaf", "Tiny Pew Pew",
 "Axe Man", "Caveman", "Like a Diamond", "Taking a Stroll", "Stand Proud",
 "Hip Replacement Surgery", "Attention Seeker", "Lone Wolf", "Uno Reverse Card"]

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content == ('!spin'):
        await message.channel.send(choice(my_list))
    if message.content == ('!spin2'):
        await message.channel.send(random.sample(my_list, 2))
    if message.content == ('!spin3'):
        await message.channel.send(random.sample(my_list, 3))
        
    if message.author == client.user:
        if "Doom" in message.content:
            await message.channel.send(random.sample(my_list, 3))
```

So while not great, it serves its purpose but when I use **!spin2** or **!spin3** the output will look something like this: `['Doom', 'Like a Diamond', 'Dukes Up']`.

Is there a way I'm able to just get the output like: `Doom, Like a Diamond, Dukes Up`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use [`join()`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/join):

```py
if message.content == ('!spin2'):
    output = ', '.join(random.sample(my_list, 2))
    await message.channel.send(output)

if message.content == ('!spin3'):
    output = ', '.join(random.sample(my_list, 3))
    await message.channel.send(output)
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you, I will have a read about join